# Why when I use parcel to build my project it removes the universal css selector?

Tags: html, css, parceljs

Im using Andy Bell's css reset and it starts with

```css
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

but when I build it becomes this

```css
*,:after,:before{box-sizing:border-box};
```

is *::after the same as :after?

Answer (score -1):

**is *::after the same as :after?**

**No it's not same because,**

Syntax:

> selector::pseudo-element {
> property: value;
> }

The ::before selector inserts something before the content of each selected element(s).

The ::after selector inserts something after the content of each selected element(s).

so you need to specify the element also with ::before and ::after selectors.

Comment: I wonder why the bundler is changing it then if they are not the same, thats what's confusing me.

Comment: @AngelReyes this answer is wrong, both are the same

Comment: @TemaniAfif Im new to css, I was so confused. lmao, thank you for clearing it up or me.